# How to access file stream of different web application using absolute URL using Server side object model

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have below code running on site **http://url:94** on 94 port and I want to read the fileStream using openBinrayStream where file is kept on another site running on **92 port**, even though I am giving the site url to spsite object it fails to access the file, and error is  Cannot open file *filename*

```
using (SPSite prSiteObj = new SPSite(http://url:92))
                            {
                                using (SPWeb prweb = prSiteObj.OpenWeb())
                                {
                                    SPFile file = prweb.GetFile(http://url:92/pathtofile.pdf);
                                    Stream contentStream = file.OpenBinaryStream();
                                    var attachment = new MailAttachment(contentStream, file.Name);
                                    email.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                                    emailAttachmentLogBuilder.Append(file.Name + "|");

                                }
                            }
```

Is there any way to read file stream of file kept on different web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the mistake which I was doing is ignoring the URL after the port number, indeed the file was on different web application but it was in a subsite of the different web application.
I had to modify the code slightly, like a below one.

```
using (SPSite prSiteObj = new SPSite(http://url:92))
                        {
                            using (SPWeb prweb = prSiteObj.OpenWeb("subsite-name"))
                            {
                                SPFile file = prweb.GetFile(http://url:92/pathtofile.pdf);
                                Stream contentStream = file.OpenBinaryStream();
                                var attachment = new MailAttachment(contentStream, file.Name);
                                email.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                                emailAttachmentLogBuilder.Append(file.Name + "|");

                            }
                        }
```

Now it's working.